# Point on plane that touches ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a plane described by:

$\overrightarrow{x} \cdot \overrightarrow{w}=c$.

Consider also the ellipsoid described by:

$(x_{1}/s_{1})^{2} + ... + (x_{N}/s_{N})^{2} = d$.

Here, *d* is such that the ellipsoid *just* touches the plane. How do I find the point where they touch?

If I'm thinking correctly, in the case of $s_{i}$ being the same for all *i*, the ellipsoid is just an N-dimensional sphere, and the point is simply where the plane intersects with its own plane vector:

Plane: $\overrightarrow{x} \cdot \overrightarrow{w}=c$.

Line: $\overrightarrow{x} = b \cdot \overrightarrow{w}$

Resulting in

$b = c / (\overrightarrow{w} \cdot \overrightarrow{w})$

$\overrightarrow{x} = \overrightarrow{w} \cdot c / (\overrightarrow{w} \cdot \overrightarrow{w})$

Gut feeling says that if $s_{i}$ are not all the same value, then this solution should be scaled by $\overrightarrow{s}$ somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. In the rescaled coordinates $z_i=x_i/s_i$,

$$z_1^2+z_2^2+\cdots z_n^2=d$$

and the transformed plane

$$(s_1w_1)z_1+(z_2w_2)z_2+\cdots(s_nw_n)z_n=c$$ is tangent to that sphere.

Hence the solution vector is parallel to the normal to the plane, $$z_i=\lambda s_iw_i$$ or $$x_i=\lambda s_i^2w_i$$ where

$$\lambda=\frac{c}{\sum (s_iw_i)^2}.$$

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: The downvote is because your answer is wrong. You should take the square root of $\lambda$.

Comment: @uniquesolution: now fixed, without a square root.

Comment: The one step I was missing was that, if $z_{i} = x_{i} / s_{i}$, then I'd need to do a similar transformation to get $v_{i} = w_{i} \cdot s_{i}$, and just use the solution that I had, except with $z$ and $v$ instead of $x$ and $w$. After that, it was easy cruising to transform back into the original $x$. So thanks!

Comment: @YvesDaoust, yes, now it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

When working with properties such as tangency that are invariant under affine transformations, scaling the coordinate system so that the ellipsoid you’re working with becomes a sphere is a good general way to simply those problems. [Yves Daoust’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2324839/265466) picks up where you left off with that approach. Since we’re looking at tangents to quadrics, another approach that can often lead to a simple solution is to use the properties of polar points and hyperplanes.

In block form, the homogeneous covector that represents the given plane is $\pi=[\mathbf w^T,-c]$ and the matrix of the ellipsoid is $$Q=\begin{bmatrix}S^{-2}&0\\0&-d\end{bmatrix},$$ where $S=\operatorname{diag}(s_1,\dots,s_N)$. Tangent planes to the ellipse satisfy the dual quadric equation $$\pi Q^{-1}\pi^T=\mathbf w^TS^2\mathbf w-\frac{c^2}d=0$$ from which $$d={c^2\over\mathbf w^TS^2\mathbf w}.\tag1$$ The polar point of a hyperplane tangent to a quadric is its only intersection with the quadric. The polar point of $\pi$ is $\mathbf p=Q^{-1}\pi^T=[\mathbf w^TS^2,c/d]^T$, which in Cartesian coordinates is $\frac dcS^2\mathbf w$. (If $c=0$, then $\pi$ passes through the origin and the ellipsoid is degenerate.) Substituting the value of $d$ from (1) and expanding gives for the point of tangency $${c\over\mathbf w^TS^2\mathbf w}S^2\mathbf w={c\over\sum_{i=1}^Ns_i^2w_i^2}(s_1^2w_1,\dots,s_N^2w_N).\tag2$$